# How could a heavy manhole cover jump out of the ground, fly through the windshield and hit a driver in a car?

Tags: kinematics, angular-momentum, momentum

Today (12 of Feb), there was this accident in Boston where a driver was killed because a manhole cover (~200lbs) had somehow become airborne and struck her. The car looks like an SUV, so her head must have been at least 1.5m from the ground.

What could cause a heavy piece of metal to fly that high?

[image]

Comment: http://indianapublicmedia.org/amomentofscience/the-case-of-the-flying-manhole-cover/

Comment: water pressure inside the sewage system??

Comment: Flipped by a vehicle ahead.